# Como tiro as caixas de explicação do Microsoft VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Olá, boa noite!

Estou programando em python pelo VSCode e sempre que escrevo alguns comandos, aparecem explicações sobre o que estou digitando, me atrapalhando pq aparece um BLOCO ENORME me explicando o que é um print(), e o que ele pode fazer...

Segue a img mostrando o que estou falando:

[Imagem do bloco de explicação do VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5N2A.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pode desativar nas definições.

Ir a File -> Preferences -> Settings

Text Editor -> Suggestions